# Disable music ticker on ambient display

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, music

I have a bootleggers [ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e-2015/orig-development/rom-bootleggers-rom-moto-e-2015-lte-t3725351) (Android 9 pie) installed on a Motorola Moto E 2015 phone and it lights the display (ambient display) every time a new song starts playing on the phone. There is a setting to toggle the "music ticker" in the bootleggers dumpster > lockscreen settings, which is turned off, but the ticker still appears.

Is it possible to disable the music ticker somewhere else?

Or maybe this is a bug of the ROM. If anybody is using Bootleggers ROM 4.2, pie, could you comment about the behaviour of the music ticker on your device?

Comment: I made a mistake. Turns out that "music ticker" and the information about the currently playing track, that I see on my ambient display are different things. "music ticker" can be toggled, as expected, in the menu bootleggers dumpster > lockscreen settings. What I am seeing are notifications from my music player app, which are pulsed on the ambient display, since at every new song the notification of the app changes and it is treated as new notifications in the ambient display, which makes it light up (or pulse) the "new" notification

Comment: I will ask a new question about the music app's notification handling on ambient display. I may delete this question if it is confusing.